# Caffe: Softmax with temperature

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, softmax

I am working on implementing Hinton's Knowledge distillation [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02531). The first step is to store the soft targets of a "cumbersome model" with a higher temperature (i.e. I don't need to train the network, just need to do forward pass per image and store the soft targets with a temperature `T`).
Is there a way I can get the output of Alexnet or googlenet soft targets but with a different temperature?
I need to modify the soft-max with `pi= exp(zi/T)/sum(exp(zi/T)`.
Need to divide the outputs of the final fully connected layer with a temperature `T`. I only need this for the forward pass (not for training).

Comment: Posted link to Hinton's paper @Shai

Answer (score 3):

I believe there are three options to solve this problem

**1.** Implement your own `Softmax` layer with a temperature parameter. It should be quite straight forward to modify the code of [`softmax_layer.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.cpp) to take into account a "temperature" `T`. You might need to tweak the [`caffe.proto`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto) as well to allow for parsing `Softmax` layer with an extra parameter.

**2.** Implement the layer as a [python layer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41481539/1714410).

**3.** If you only need a forward pass, i.e. "extracting features", then you can simply output as features the "top" of the layer **before** the softmax layer and do the softmax with temperature outside caffe altogether.

**4.** You can add [`Scale`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto#L1062-L1097) layer before the top `Softmax` layer:

```
layer {
  type: "Scale"
  name: "temperature"
  bottom: "zi"
  top: "zi/T"
  scale_param { 
    filler: { type: 'constant' value: 1/T }  # replace "1/T" with the actual value of 1/T.
  }
  param { lr_mult: 0 decay_mult: 0 } # make sure temperature is fixed
}
layer {
  type: "Softmax"
  name: "prob"
  bottom: "zi/T"
  top: "pi"
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will try the first option.